# How can I play a video within a Confluence wiki page?

Tags: video, wiki, confluence

Inserting a video within a Confluence wiki page just link to it:

[image]

How can I play a video within a Confluence wiki page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the the [multimedia macro](https://support.atlassian.com/confluence-cloud/docs/insert-the-multimedia-macro/):

[image]

[image]